# Listen to filtered events using web3js 0.19 (provided by infura)

Tags: web3js, events

I am working on a uport dApp. uPort by default uses web3 from rinkeby.infura.io which is web3 version 0.19. So no WebSocket available. I tried `ZeroClientProvider` but that leads to this error:

```
Error in ./~/eth-block-tracker/src/index.js
Module parse failed: C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\projUport\node_modules\eth-block-tracker\src\index.js Unexpected token (38:8)
Module parse failed: C:\Users\Rahul\Desktop\projUport\node_modules\eth-json-rpc-infura\src\index.js Unexpected token (25:54)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (25:54)
 @ ./~/eth-json-rpc-infura/src/createProvider.js 3:31-49
```

My code for it was:

```
const ProviderEngine = require('web3-provider-engine/index.js');
const ZeroClientProvider = require('web3-provider-engine/zero.js');
const engine = ZeroClientProvider({
  getAccounts: function(){},
  rpcUrl: "https://rinkeby.infura.io/INFURA_KEY", 
})
const web3 = new Web3(engine);`
```

Using `contractInstance.eventName({<filters..>}).watch(callback)` or anything similar shows the following error: `405 POST ERROR rinkeby.infura.io` I have seen their github issues (https://github.com/INFURA/infura/issues/13, https://github.com/INFURA/infura/issues/10), but nothing seemed to be useful.
No matter whatever I do, I can't seem to get web3 1.0 (tried setting providers as `wss://rinkeby.infura.io/ws` or `rinkeby.infura.io/INFURA_KEY`.

Its been over 2 hours and I have tried several different approaches.
Please post any that works with either web3 0.19 or uport dApp!

**EDIT: MINIMUM CODE:- 
SOLIDITY**:

```
public uint id;
event TaskCreated(uint _id);
function addTask(uint _id) {
    id++; emit Taskcreated(_id); }
```

**JS:**

```
contractABI = <abi>
contractInstance = contractABI.at(<contract_address>);
var taskCreatedEvent = contractInstance.TaskCreated( {fromBlock:0, toBlock: 'latest' })
await taskCreatedEvent.watch((err,res) => {
            if (!err) {
                console.log(res);
                let id = res.args.id.toNumber();
                console.log(id)
            }
        })
```

Comment: Can you share a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the code you are trying to get working?

Comment: just added. Hope its enough to understand.

Comment: Infura doesn't support filtering events, it does support subscription using websockets (and that requires web3 v1.0). If you are on web3 v0.20 you can use [Web3 Provider Engine](https://github.com/MetaMask/provider-engine/) to filter events.

Comment: Using the web3 Provider Engine gives an error. So can't use that